# Mixin function that takes in some css and returns media queries that auto increment / decrement some values

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I am currently stuck figuring out following use case:

I have made a mixin that returns media queries for it's content (here `$breakpoint` variables are just some values defined above in the file)

```
@mixin responsive {
    @media screen and (min-width: $breakpointXS) {
        @content;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: $breakpointSM) {
        @content;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: $breakpointMD) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

I can then use this mixin as follows

```
.myElement {
    @include responsive {
        height: 20px;
        width: 50px;
    }
}
```

But as you can see it basically compiles to those 3 media queries with same content in them. What I am trying to figure out is following

1. Have that 1 mixin `responsive`, but somehow pass base values to it i.e. `20px` for height and `50px` for width.
2. Then use these base values in `XS` media query, but multiply them by `1.2` in `SM` media query and by `1.6` in `MD` media query.

Thus end goal is to have one mixin function where I pass base css / base values to be used in smallest screen media query and have it output other ones programatically by incrementing / multiplying these base values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the `@content` on the condition that the content is defined as such using the `using` keyword, for your example that would be:

```
@mixin responsive {
    @media screen and (min-width: $breakpointXS) {
        @content(1);
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: $breakpointSM) {
        @content(1.2);
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: $breakpointMD) {
        @content(1.6);
    }
}
```

and the usage becomes

```
.myElement {
    @include responsive using ($multiplier) {
        height: 20px * $multiplier;
        width: 50px * $multiplier;
    }
}
```